# C++ code working as intended on Linux but not on Windows

Tags: c++

I do not know why this code breaks ,probably when adding new node, on Windows .Returns "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"),it was compiled with GNU GCC.It works perfectly fine on Linux.
   Also tested on geeksforgeeks ide , this is the link https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/feo8SYMsFP.
When debugged, SIGSEGV is returned when adding node but I am not sure why..
For example, input : 1 10 1 11 then it breaks..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Node
{
    int key;
    Node * left;
    Node * right;
};
class binarySearchTree
{
private:
    Node *root;
    Node *newNode(int key)
    {
        Node *temp = new Node;
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
        temp->key = key;
        return temp;
    }
    void traverse_inorder(Node *temp)
    {
        if (temp==NULL)
            return;

        traverse_inorder(temp->left);
        std::cout <<"Current key: "<< temp->key << "\n";
        traverse_inorder(temp->right);

    }
    void find(Node* temp,int key)
    {

        if (temp==NULL)
            return;
        find(temp->left,key);
        if (temp->key == key)
            std::cout <<"Key " << key << " found\n";
        find(temp->right,key);
    }
    Node* minValueNode(Node* n)
    {
        Node* x = n;
        while (x->left != NULL)
            x = x->left;
        return x;
    }
    Node* deleteNode(Node* temp, int key)
    {
        if (temp == NULL)
            return temp;
        if (key < temp->key)
            temp->left = deleteNode(temp->left, key);
        else if (key > temp->key)
            temp->right = deleteNode(temp->right, key);
        else
        {
            if (temp->left == NULL)
            {
                Node *x = temp->right;
                delete temp;
                return x;
            }
            else if (root->right == NULL)
            {
                Node *x = temp->left;
                delete temp;
                return x;
            }
            Node* x = minValueNode(temp->right);
            temp->key = x->key;
            temp->right = deleteNode(temp->right, x->key);
        }
        return temp;
    }
    void delete_tree(Node *temp)
    {
        if (temp == NULL)
            return;
        delete_tree(temp->left);
        delete_tree(temp->right);
        delete temp;

    }
    void traverse_postorder(Node* temp)
    {
        if (temp == NULL)
            return;
        traverse_postorder(temp->left);
        traverse_postorder(temp->right);
        std::cout <<"Current key: "<< temp->key << "\n";
    }
    void traverse_preorder(Node* temp)
    {
        if (temp == NULL)
            return;
        std::cout <<"Current key: "<< temp->key << "\n";
        traverse_preorder(temp->left);
        traverse_preorder(temp->right);
    }
    void add(int key)
    {
        if (root == NULL)
            root = newNode(key);
        else
        {
            Node *temp = root;
            while (true)
            {
                if (temp->key > key)
                {
                    if (temp->left == NULL)
                    {
                        temp->left = newNode(key);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        temp = temp->left;
                }
                else if (temp->key < key)
                {
                    if (temp->right == NULL)
                    {
                        temp->right =newNode(key);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        temp = temp->right;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "Key already added!\n";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
public:

    binarySearchTree()
    {
        root = NULL;
    }
    ~binarySearchTree()
    {
        delete_tree(root);
    }
    void _find(int key)
    {
        find(root,key);
    }
    void _del(int key)
    {
        root = deleteNode(root,key);
    }
    void _traverse_postorder()
    {
        traverse_postorder(root);
    }
    void _traverse_preorder()
    {
        traverse_preorder(root);
    }
    void _traverse_inorder()
    {
        traverse_inorder(root);
    }
    void _add(int key)
    {
        add(key);
    }

};
int main()
{
    binarySearchTree bst;
    std::cout << "Binary Search Tree Menu (1-add key, 2-search key, 3-remove key, 4-traverse inorder, 5-traverse postorder, 6-traverse preorder, q-exit)\n";
    char input;
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Awaiting input ";
        std::cin >> input;
        int key;

        switch(input)
        {
        case '1':
            std::cout << "Enter key.. ";
            std::cin >> key;
            bst._add(key);
            break;
        case '2':
            std::cout << "Enter key.. ";
            std::cin >> key;
            bst._find(key);
            break;
        case '3':
            std::cout << "Enter key.. ";
            std::cin>>key;
            bst._del(key);
            break;
        case '4':
            bst._traverse_inorder();
            break;
        case '5':
            bst._traverse_postorder();
            break;
        case '6':
            bst._traverse_preorder();
            break;


        }
    }
    while (input != 'q');
    std::cout << "Deleting Binary Search Tree...\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @M.M thanks a lot ! problem solved ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
struct Node
{
    int key;
    Node * left;
    Node * right;
};

Node *newNode(int key)
{
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->key = key;
    return temp;
}
```

means that `newNode` returns pointer to node with indeterminate values for `left` and `right`. Instead these should be null pointers,  (e.g. use `new Node();` instead of `new Node;`).

On the original system it probably happened to get zeroed memory from the allocator so the problem didn't show up.

Comment: Being a pretty odd behaviour, you should expand on the difference between `new Node();` and `new Node;`. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new) would be a nice reference, since it actually describes it.

Comment: @LoPiTaL my answer already says that this will make them null pointers instead of uninitialized ...